# Css наследование

Tags: html, css, html5, css3, наследование

Собственно вопрос: Почему в `div>p` цвета не красные? `id` же приоритетом выше чем атрибут. Или `p` не наследует параметров `div`, хотя `font-weight` наследуется.

Был бы рад если подкинули статью.

```css
p{
  color: gold;
}
#p{
  font-weight: bold;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
  <div id="p">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor.</p>
  <p>Temporibus, voluptate, praesentium.</p>
  <p>Itaque, quo nihil.</p>
  <p>Repudiandae, consequatur, rem?</p>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Автор вы перемешали котлеты и мух . Вы представьте реальную вёрстку и блокам div нужно давать чёткие имена т.е если вы хотите что бы все параграфы внутри определённого блока были красным то так и пишите : .text-red>p{color:red;} а если вы пишите что p{некие стили} то все параграфы унаследуют именно эти стили но до тех пор пока не указано иное

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Вы правы в том, что `id` выше приоритетом, чем сам тэг. Но приоритет выше относительно тэга, к которому относится `id`, т.е. у `<div>`. Что касается `<p>`, то у него есть более подходящий селектор, тот в котором указан именно этот тэг.

Иными словами, `<p>` наследовал параметры `<div id="p">`, но они были переопределены.

Статью не посоветую, но посоветую книгу:

> Макфарланд Дэвид - Большая книга CSS3. 3-е изд. — СПб.: Питер, 2014. — 608 с.: ил. — (Серия «Бестселлеры O’Reilly»). ISBN 978-5-496-00428-2.

Comment: прошу прощения - kff